# Using prepared statements with SQLite3 and PHP

Tags: php, sqlite, prepared-statement, prepare

I'm trying to add data to a database using SQLite3 in PHP. I got it working without prepared statements but now I'm trying to make it safer. I'm not using PDO.

So far the following code doesn't work. It just inserts the words ":name" and ":email" into the database, instead of what their bound values should be:

```
$smt = $db->prepare("insert into names (name, email) values (':name', ':email')");
$smt->bindValue(':name', $var_name);
$smt->bindValue(':email', $var_email);

$var_name = ($_POST[post_name]);
$var_email = ($_POST[post_email]);

$smt->execute();
```

So I thought at first that this was because I have single quotes around `:name` and `:email` in the prepared statement. So I took those out. Now when I post the form, it just puts blank entries into the database, it doesn't insert the values of `$var_name` and `$var_email`

The statement *is* executing, it's just not binding the variables properly I don't think. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Maybe, adding a type of data will help: SQLITE3_TEXT?  Though, it's optional. http://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3stmt.bindvalue.php

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention that I have tried that too, thanks though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You managed to confuse binding functions.

It is **bindParam** have to be used if you don't have your variable assigned yet.
While **bindValue** have to be used with existing value only.

Also, you should turn **error reporting ON**

Comment: Oh wait, execute only accepts parameters when using PDO, I said in my question that I was not using PDO.. How can I get it to work WITHOUT PDO?

Comment: Well, then read aforementioned functions descriptions and use them properly

Answer (score 4):

You don't need intermediate variables, you must do this:

```
$smt = $db->prepare("insert into names (name, email) values (':name', ':email')");
$smt->bindValue(':name', $_POST['post_name'], SQLITE3_TEXT);
$smt->bindValue(':email', $_POST['post_email'], SQLITE3_TEXT);

$smt->execute();
```

As documented in [`SQLite3Stmt::bindValue()`](https://php.net/sqlite3stmt.bindvalue) value is binded instantly, not as [`SQLite3Stmt::bindParam()`](https://php.net/sqlite3stmt.bindparam) that gets the value of the variable at `execute()` time. So the problem is that that variables are empty when the statement is executed.

---

Remember:

- You don't need to add parentheses on variable assignment: $a = ($b); -> $a = $b;
- You MUST quote variable key name. Otherwise PHP will try to look for a constant with this name and will throw a warning if it doesn't exists... but will assign a erroneous key value if it exists!! `$_POST[post_name]` -> `$_POST['post_name']`